# Python - Download Zip File and Extract All

Tags: python

I have two with block, one to download the zipped file and another one to extract all files. When I use them separately it works but when I use them together I receive an error saying BadZipFile. Here's an example of my code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import zipfile

f = open(r'C:\file.zip', 'wb')

with FTP("ftp.website.com") as ftp:
    ftp.login(user='USER', passwd='PASSWORD')
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + 'file.zip', f.write, 1024)

with zipfile.ZipFile('file.zip', 'r') as z:
    z.extractall()
```

Comment: Why not just use them separately ? I use urllib to grab the tar.gz/zip from a web server) then tarfile/zipfile to extract. Just make sure the file has finished being downloaded before trying to unzip/extract. You should add some exception handling for ftp ,file io/unziping(remember to import the ftp errors as importing FTP from ftplib doesn't import them)

Comment: Have you tried not using the 3rd parameter in retrbinary ? Cause skipping data could easily create a corrupted .zip file.

Comment: I added f.close() between both with and it worked.

Comment: do you really need to open and close it ? Just get the file and extract it. Unless windows needs you to do that ?

Comment: I removed the 3rd parameter in retrbinary, thank you Laurent.

Comment: I tried to remove open and close but I get another error. Also, if I do that, I don't know what to put in the second argument of retrbinary.